# Using glob with comma in path folder

Tags: php, glob

I'm using glob function to get the contents of a folder. It's working fine but when the folder name looks like this `Test, Folder` it doesn't work and returns an empty array.

My code:

```
$path = 'upload/Test, Folder';
print_r(glob(ABSPATH.$path."/*.*"));
```

Comment: Then that must not be the correct name of the folder. `glob()` doesn't treat comma specially. Are you sure there's a single space after the comma in the folder name?

Comment: 100% sure it's just like the example

Comment: Which is more likely, that a well-tested function like `glob()` has a serious bug like this, or that you've made a mistake in the folder name?

Comment: Does `ABSPATH` end with `/`?

Comment: Yes it does, it's from wordpress and I'm using the same code with a lot other folders already, the only one with the bug is folders like this.

Comment: Could it be a tab, or some other character that looks like a space? If you try to access a known file in the folder, does that work? E.g. `var_dump(file_exists(ABSPATH.$path."/filename"));`?

Comment: The only time that comma has special meaning is inside a brace list if the `GLOB_BRACE` flag is set.